# How to remove stubborn paint spots from natural stone

Tags: stone, paint-removal

My upstate NY porch floor was built with stone quarried from northern PA.  The previous owner got some white paint drips on it which I would like to remove.  What I've tried so far:

- mineral spirits
- Sealkrete Clean-N-Etch concrete 2-in-1 cleaner & etcher

Neither of these made ANY difference whatsoever.  I even tried the Sealkrete undiluted.

The only other thing I can think of is straight muriatic acid.

Comment: Goof off soak then pressure washer  maybe

Comment: @Kris - It hardly seems worth it to rent a pressure washer for three paint spots.  Wire brush instead?

Comment: I read somewhere that paint spots were removed from large stones by the generous application of cow manure and leaving for 24hours... Apparently left nor residues either....

Comment: @SolarMike - Is it the ammonia?  I don't have any cows handy, but I have a bottle of ammonia for cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion that you made in comments to try a wire brush may very well be a good first effort. However I would like to suggest some additional things as well.

1. Try to see if most of the paint spot can be removed by scraping at it with a sharp edged scraper or knife. This should be able to get most of the paint removed if it has any significant thickness like many paint dips have.
2. Most paint can be softened most easily with paint stripper. This would be most effective when most of the paint thickness has already been mechanically removed. Stripper can also help get out some of the paint that may have penetrated into a rough or porous stone surface. Before using do experiment with the stripper by applying some to an inconspicuous area to make sure the harsh chemicals in the stripper do not absorb into the stone and permanently discolor it.
3. Using a wire brush or coarse steel will would be tools of choice for removing the last remnants of the paint after the scraping and stripping. In the end there may remain some small amount of discoloration that cannot be removed without seriously abrading the stone.